# a:active does not work in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm having another battle with IE. I'm working on my school's athletics website, and grudgingly got around to making it IE compatible. I've fixed most of the issues, but this last one has me totally baffled.

I look at simple scripts such as http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/WVrzu/16/ and the active selector works. However, the :active state on the navigation bar does not work. You can see it here: http://mageelions.ca/athletics/forms.php (download active state does not work either). It's perfectly fine in other browsers, but this "lack of active state" is bothering me.

ie.css:

```
ul#nav_buttons li a:active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: rgb(150,60,60) url("../images/default-red-down.png") !important;
}
```

`a:hover` is fine... if anyone knows how to fix this it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for me with IE9 in all three browser modes that the dev tools offer (IE7 upwards).

Comment: IE9 works for me: http://i.imgur.com/kttlP.png

Comment: `a:active` works in IE4+; `:active` on other elements is IE8+.

Comment: Do students use IE? The horror

Comment: @Keyser The school probably does.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I was under the impression that this athletics website was for the students' benefit though. Might not be the case. Still, that's not much better :p. And yes my point is that we should ignore IE-support until they get the message ("they" being Microsoft of course).

Comment: @Keyser Yes, my school only has IE installed on most computers and they don't get it when it messes up :P . I'm on IE9, but tried all the different browser modes (7-9). Still not working for me?

Comment: @Raeki If it's working for other people and not you then the problem must be somewhere else. In my experience it can be anything with IE. Syntax and Semantics in the code you provided is the only thing that's been ruled out.

Comment: @Keyser interesting... I have cleared the browser cache but it still shows the same. I will get back when I can test it on the school computers tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

do you respect the correct order? IE is sensitive to those things:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

if you mix up, IE wont do stuff as expected.

Comment: The esteemable [Eric Myers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/06/11/who-ordered-the-link-states/) *Lord Vader Hits Furry Animals* (LVHFA, LVFA) and [explained it in some detail](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/06/04/ordering-the-link-states/)... five years ago. At least he was [specific](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html).

Comment: I don't use a:link or a:visited (though I do have plain a), but active does come after hover

Comment: you know that :active is only the moment when you click?

Answer (score 0):

Does the version of IE you're using support `rgb()` notation? Try using the equivalent hex instead:

```
ul#nav_buttons li a:active {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #963c3c url("../images/default-red-down.png") !important;
}
```